# Spawning threads inside a class

Tags: c++, multithreading

I'm getting an compilation error, related to `std::invoke`, and also another that can not specialize the template for `invoke`.
This is the code:

```
#pragma once
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <chrono>

class ThreadLoader {
private:
    unsigned int id;
    void _loadFile(const std::string& filepath) {
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
        std::cout << "Loading " << filepath << "\n";
    }
public:
    static unsigned int counter;
    ThreadLoader() {
        id = counter;
        counter++;
    }

    void loadFile(const std::string& filepath) {
        std::thread t(&ThreadLoader::_loadFile, std::ref(filepath), this);
        t.join();
    }

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const ThreadLoader& t) {
        return os << t.id << std::endl;
    }
};

unsigned int ThreadLoader::counter = 0;
```

The error appears when I tried to call the `loadFile` function.
I already checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50654452/c-error-when-threading-stdinvoke/50654520). I think followed the accepted answer, however, the error persists. I think that I'm doing something wrong in `std::thread t(&ThreadLoader::_loadFile, std::ref(filepath), this);`, but I don't find what is it.

Comment: I think it should be `std::cref`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have your parameters the wrong way round, it should be:

```
std::thread t(&ThreadLoader::_loadFile, this, std::ref(filepath));
```

Comment: Hi Paul. May I ask why we need the `this` keyword? I checked the signature of thread constructor, the arguments start from the second position. Why is `std::thread t(&ThreadLoader::_loadFile, std::ref(filepath));` not OK ?

Comment: It's needed because `_loadFile` is a member function, rather than a free function, so you need an instance of `ThreadLoader` to call it on.